# renderMarkdown locally vs. shiny-server

Tags: r, markdown, shiny-server

For a shiny application, I have a small issue with renderMarkdown.

Consider a text file with the following simple contents:

```
Markdown Test File

+ Item 1
+ Item 2
```

Let's save this file as "Markdown Test.txt". Now, let's read it in and process it, using the following R code:

```
filename <- "Markdown Test.txt"
text.in  <- readLines(filename)
text.out <- renderMarkdown(text=text.in)
```

When I run this locally - i.e. on my Windows machine - I get:

```
> text.out
[1] "<p>Markdown Test File</p>\n\n<ul>\n<li>Item 1</li>\n<li>Item 2</li>\n</ul>\n"
```

This looks good. However, running the same code on the machine that hosts shiny server, I get:

```
> text.out
[1] "<p>Markdown Test File+ Item 1+ Item 2</p>\n"
```

As you can see, the Markdown conversion is far from perfect; e.g. the list is not converted.

On the Windows machine I have:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United    States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

On the shiny machine, I get:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

So, I'm assuming that this has to do with the encoding, but the little I know about encoding I wish I didn't... my experiments with dos2unix and Sys.setlocale() let to nothing but frustration.

Would anyone happen to have a clever "one liner" that can fix this? Any help appreciated!

Thanks, Philipp

Comment: So are we to assume the shiny machine is a unix machine? Does the file have proper line breaks when you `cat` the file on the unix machine?

Comment: Yes, the shiny machine is a Unix machine. When I do cat, I get the exact same output on both machines:

    > cat(text.in)
    Markdown Test File  + Item 1 + Item 2>

Comment: cat of a windows file will work find on a unix box, unfortunately.
A better test is to use `file` on it, which will tell you both the line endings and the character set in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if R has a dedicated package to fix line encodings, but one way is to use `sub` to replace `\r\n` with `\n` (or just strip `\r`s).